# Expect/TCL simple proc/variable issue

Tags: linux, variables, tcl, expect, procedure

I have an expect script which works but I have attempted to remove duplicate code and use a proc however the string passed to the proc does not seem to be getting used.

As this is my first exposure to TCL/expect it is probably something basic to do with variable passing/usage.

I had (worked):

```
    expect {
        "CONDITION" {}
        timeout { various cleanup operations; send_user "a message"; exit 1 }
    }
```

and changed it to (broken):

```
    proc exit_on_error {message} {
        various cleanup operations
        send_user "$message"
        exit 1
    }
    expect {
        "CONDITION" {}
        timeout { exit_on_error "a message" }
    }
```

it does all the cleanup operations and exits but send_user seems to have empty string

```
    send_user $message
```

complains about wrong number of arguments.

Comment: I tried your example and it works. The problem might be in your clean up code. You might want to call `send_user` before cleaning up. Would you please post the error message?

Comment: I should add this is embedded within a bash script invoked by: `expect <<- DONE` it is not a proper expect script.  I think it might be getting confused between bash variables and expect variables

Comment: Yes, when embedded within bash, I see your behavior. I am trying to find out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bash is expanding the `$message` variable in the here-doc **before** sending the doc to expect.

If you do not rely on using shell variables in the expect script, single quote the here-doc:

```
expect <<-'DONE'
```

Otherwise, choose one of these options to protect the Tcl variable expansion from the shell:

```
send_user \$message
send_user [set message]
```

Tcl does not require you to quote the variable: it expands the variable but maintains the value as a single word.

Comment: I'd *really* think hard about putting the Tcl code in a separate file. Tcl+Expect scripts conventionally have the extension `.exp` but `.tcl` would be fine too…